How do I snap object edges to other object edges?
I have two meshes, grass and wall, and I want to snap their edges together so there isn't any holes in the mesh when I combine them.
This is what I want to accomplish:
.
It was done manually and it has a lot of holes and looks terrible.

Can you not just extrude the wall down from the grass, as part of the same object, and separate them afterwards?

@RobinBetts yes, but there are more types of islands that i wanna make and they have walls that curve in some direction and I dont want to remake them.

Hi, Guy.. I think to avoid suggestions like mine, it would be good to share a few examples on https://blend-exchange.com/ , making them as tricky as possible for us to fix, so we can cover the cases.

Okay, i'll do that next time.

.. you can do it now, and edit the provided link into your post :)

I can't, as I am not home and the comments are from my phone.

You can use snapping:

Select both objects and enter edit mode
Select a wall vertex and shift-select the corresponding grass vertex
Perform "Snap selection to Active", for example by pressing shift+s

You can also activate snapping and set it to snap to Vertex, then you can just grab a wall vertex and it will just snap to the corresponding grass vertex:

A potentially faster method:

Select the wall edge-ring and delete the faces
Select the grass edge-loop, duplicate, separate and then join it with the wall object
Keep the grass edge-loop selected and shift select the wall's ground edge-loop
Perform "Bridge Edge Loops" (ctrl+e)

